# Reset does not work a form in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

All I want to do is when I click the reset button on my form it resets all fields. And I have tried everything but it does not seem to work. Here is the class that has the button in it:

```
App.views.HomeIndex = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel,{
                    floating: true,
            scroll: 'vertical',
                    itemId: 'jobSearch',
            centered: true,
            modal: true,
            hideOnMaskTap: false,
            items: [{  
            xtype: 'textfield',
            itemId: 'keywords',
            label: 'Keywords',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            labelWidth: '100%',
            name: 'keywords'
            },{  
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Job Title',
            itemId: 'jtitle',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            labelWidth: '100%',
            name: 'jtitle'
            },{
            .... //more xtypes here
                     ,
                dockedItems: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        itemId: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'bottom',
                        height: '36',
                        items: [
                            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Reset',itemId: 'resetBtn',
                            },
                            { xtype: 'spacer'},
                            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Submit',itemId:'submitBtn',ui: 'action',
                           }                                                   
                            ]
                    }]
```

In my App.js I have the code to handle the reset method: 
//this is one way I thought of doing it. But obviously it does not work. I have tried googling all over but couldnt find a solution.

```
this.homeView.query('#resetBtn')[0].setHandler(function(){
         var form = this.el.up('.x-panel');
         //form.down('.x-input-text[name=keywords]').setValue(' ');
    form.query('#jobSearch').getComponent('keywords').reset();              
        });


            });

    Ext.reg('HomeIndex', App.views.HomeIndex);
```

Comment: Are you checking to see what form.query('#jobSearch').getComponent('keywords') is giving you? I feel like your var form and your query is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your form's ID is "jobSearch", the name is "keyboards". You're trying to combine both.

Try:

```
form.query('#jobSearch').reset();
```

or:

```
document.forms['keywords'].reset();
```

Comment: form.query gives: TypeError: Object  has no method 'reset'

and document.forms gives  Cannot call method 'reset' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a bit more ExtJS like.

```
var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#jobSearch .form')[0];
form.reset();
```

Comment: It says :  Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined